# Functions of possibly cyclic data structures

Tags: haskell, data-structures

If I have a recursive ADT

```
data MyType = A | B | C MyType | D MyType MyType
```

I could write a function to determine whether an instance of `MyType` contains an `A` like so:

```
hasA :: MyType -> Bool
hasA A = True
hasA B = False
hasA (C x) = hasA x
hasA (D x y) = (hasA x) || (hasA y)
```

This would work for acyclic instances, but it does not halt for cyclic structures, e.g.

```
let x = C x in hasA x
```

Instead, in this example it should return `False`. In other cases (making use of `D`) it would erroneously not halt instead of returning `True`.

So, the question is how do I most easily write functions like `hasA` that work on cyclic structures? [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) has a particularly nice feature for this in the form of `define/fix`, that allows you to make a function like `hasA` behave as intended and return `False` for the structure in the example above, with hardly any extra code. Is there a way of doing something similar in Haskell? Is there an extension for it?

Edit: I have now found that `define/fix` is in fact [a macro created by Matt Might](http://matt.might.net/articles/parsing-with-derivatives/code/dparse.rkt) that takes advantage of Racket's meta-programming features, not a built-in feature, but this does not make it any less of a great feature of Racket. Maybe this macro could be reproduced in Haskell?

Comment: you'll definitely have to reify cycles in your graph, or keep track of the data you need for `hasA` in some other way when you construct it (e.g. at the top level have a `Set` of all the structures below). This might have some good info for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732084/how-do-you-represent-a-graph-in-haskell

Comment: @jberryman What about using `StableName` for equality tests to detect cycles? Is there a downside to that that I have missed? And thank you very much for that link.

Comment: @Dylan using `StableName` to check for equality should be fine for this.  The only downside I can think of is that it operates in IO.

Comment: @JohnL Would it be "safe" to use that with unsafePerformIO for this purpose?

Comment: @Dylan: No!  Purity is exactly why `StableName` lives in `IO`.  Equational reasoning says that `let x = C x in hasA x` should be the same as `let x = C x in hasA (C x)`, but `StableName`s would let you violate that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key words to search for on Hackage are [observable sharing](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=observable+sharing). The [data-reify](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-reify) package in those results looks especially relevant:

> `data-reify` provided [sic] the ability to turn recursive structures into explicit graphs. Many (implicitly or explicitly) recursive data structure can be given this ability, via a type class instance. This gives an alternative to using Ref for observable sharing.

Comment: Very nice links. Just what I was looking for. Thanks.