# Representing and building a cyclic abstract syntax tree

Tags: haskell, data-structures, typeclass

I'm a newbie Haskell programmer with imperative background.

I'm writing a program that parses an abstract syntax tree (or rather a graph) that has cycles. (This is actually GCC's Generic AST). I'm designing data types for representing this graph, but I'm facing difficulties:

Firstly, there are lots of nasty cycles in GCC AST. For example type declarations refer to the actual type descriptor which refers back to the type's declaration (and this declaration may sometimes be different from the original, sometimes it is just a reference to an identifier node). All tree nodes reference a so-called context node (a form of parent reference). However, this context node (for some node X) often is not the same as the node that originally referred to X. For example a declaration for some builtin function may be found from a C++ namespace node, but the function declaration's context points to a translation unit declaration. Perhpas this makes using zippers impossible? Also I can't just ignore these context nodes, because they are useful for finding out the scope of declarations.

So, when designing the data structure I should take into account the fact, that sometimes I don't know what kind of node I will be dealing with at run time. However, when I'm certain that a node will have a known type, I would like to be able to reflect this on type level and take advantage of static type checking (for example function's result type is always a type, not an integer constant, but it might be integer or pointer type, etc.).

Secondly, GCC tree is a hierarchical data type in object-oriented sense. All nodes have common information, such as what kind of node they are. All declarations have a name and many flags, and variable declarations have type information in addition. Many nodes have so much data that it would be incovenient to access this information through pattern matching only. So I most likely will be using accessor functions (and type classes to provide an uniform interface regardless of the node type).

Thirdly, I would like my graph to be purely functional, but I don't know how to build it. My input is text, which has a section for every node. Nodes are identified by unique ids, and there are lots of forward- and self-references.

So, with my background, I sense that I'm trying to force my Haskell interface to an imperative form. So I'm asking you for some concrete advice to guide me in designing my data types, their interface and how to build the graph.

So far I have decided that I will not be tying the knot. It would prevent me from doing transformations on the tree (which IMHO deserves some transformations). It also would make it hard to write this tree back to disc, if I want to do that some day.

EDIT:
Here is a sample of my input. It is in YAML, but the format is not yet set to stone (I'm generating this data my self from within GCC).
http://sange.fi/~aura/test.yaml The example contains the global namespace with one function declaration for (int main (int argc, char *argv[])).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would be easier to help with if you can actually show us some cod, what does the AST look like?

Comment: did you read the question and discussion from yesterday?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you represent a graph in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732084/how-do-you-represent-a-graph-in-haskell)