# How to declare data constructor for graphs

Tags: haskell, graph, constructor

Below I give data constructors for list and trees.

```
data List a = NilL | Cons a (List a) deriving Show
data Tree a = NilT | Branch a [Tree a] deriving Show
```

With these definitions I can create infinite structures easily as shown below:

```
list = Cons 1 list
tree = Branch 1 lt
 where
  lt = tree : lt
```

I want to create infinite graphs (both directed and undirected) in this manner. How to declare a data constructor for it and how to create an infinite graph using that data constructor in Haskell?

Comment: You might also like ["How do you represent a graph in Haskell?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9732084/791604).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to use some form of indirection, like indices

```
type Vertex = Integer
data Graph = Graph [Vertex] [(Vertex, Vertex)]

infGraph = Graph [1..] [(a, b) | a <- [1..], b <- [1..]]
```

However this isn't quite as satisfying as knot tying

```
data Vertex = Vertex { tag   :: Integer
                     , edges :: [Vertex] }

type Graph = [Vertex] -- A graph is determined by the set of vertices

-- Construct a graph of infinitely many vertices in which
-- each vertex is connected.
infGraph = map (flip Vertex infGraph) [1..]
infGraph' = map (\v' -> v' infGraph') . map Vertex $ [1..]
```

We `map` `Vertex` over `[1..]` which gives us a list of functions `[Vertex] -> Vertex` which want a list of edges to connect each vertex to. Since `infGraph` is the list of all vertices, we pass that to each `Vertex` and tie the knot.

Of course for serious work, use a [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.2.0.1/docs/Data-Graph.html).

Comment: In the second one, you gave `type Graph = [Vertex]`, I didn't not understand how do you get the edges from this thing? please explain it.

Comment: @TemPora Look at the definition of vertices, the edges are embedded in the vertices.

Comment: Thanks. I had saw the previous definition for it. Got confused how Integer can handle all this things. Sorry.

Comment: @TemPora No problem, does this answer your question?

Comment: It seems to work but I not understand how the magic happening in the `map (flip Vertex infGraph) [1..]`. Can you explain a bit about how and why the map is used?

Comment: Thanks. You write: `-- Construct a graph of infinitely many vertices in which -- each vertex is connected.` Is it do you mean, `--each vertex is connected to all the vertices`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40522/discussion-between-tem-pora-and-jozefg)