# Should a Foldable always return all its results exactly once?

Tags: haskell, graph, typeclass, contract, foldable

Here's a type for cyclic, directed graphs with labelled nodes and edges.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Monoid

data Node n e = N n [(e, Node n e)]  -- the node's label and its list of neighbors
newtype Graph n e = G (M.Map n (Node n e))
```

To handle the case where the graph has a loop, it's [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9732857/1523776) to 'tie the knot' and create infinitely recursive graphs in finite space.

```
type GraphInput n e = M.Map n [(e, n)]

mkGraph :: Ord n => GraphInput n e -> Graph n e
mkGraph spec = G $ nodeMap
    where nodeMap = M.mapWithKey mkNode (makeConsistent spec)
          -- mkNode :: n -> [(e, n)] -> Node n e
          mkNode lbl edges = N lbl $ map getEdge edges
          -- We know that (!) can't fail because we ensured that
          -- all edges have a key in the map (see makeConsistent)
          getEdge (e, lbl) = (e, nodeMap ! lbl)

makeConsistent :: Ord n => GraphInput n e -> GraphInput n e
makeConsistent m = foldr addMissing m nodesLinkedTo
    where addMissing el m = M.insertWith (\_ old -> old) el [] m
          nodesLinkedTo = map snd $ join $ M.elems m
```

By viewing the graph as a collection of nodes, we can write a `Foldable` instance which performs a depth-first traversal.*

```
newtype NodeGraph e n = NG {getNodeGraph :: Graph n e}

instance Foldable (NodeGraph e) where
    foldMap f (NG (G m)) = foldMap mapNode (M.elems m)
        where mapNode (N n es) = f n `mappend` foldMap mapEdge es
              mapEdge (e, n) = mapNode n
```

However, even for simple tree-shaped graphs, this produces duplicate elements:

```
--   A
--  / \    X
-- B   C
--     |
--     D
ghci> let ng = NG $ mkGraph [('A', [(1, 'B'), (1, 'C')]), ('C', [(1, 'D')]), ('X', [])]
ghci> let toList = Data.Foldable.foldr (:) []
ghci> toList ng
"ABCDBCDDX"
```

When the graph has a cycle, the effect is even more dramatic - `foldMap` recurses forever! The items in the loop are repeated, and some elements are never returned!

Is this okay? Can a instance of `Foldable` return some of its elements more than once, or am I violating the contract of the class? Can an instance loop on a part of the structure infinitely? I've been looking for guidance on this issue - I was hoping for a set of 'Foldable laws' that would settle the question - but I haven't been able to find any discussion of the question online.

---

One approach to get out of this would be to 'remember' the elements which have already been visited as I traverse the graph. However, this would add an `Eq` or `Ord` constraint to the signature of `foldMap`, which precludes my type being a member of `Foldable`.

<sub>* Incidentally, we can't write a `Functor` instance for `NodeGraph`, because it would break the invariant that nodes in a graph are uniquely labelled. (`fmap (const "foo")`, for example, will relabel every node to "foo", though they'll all have different sets of edges!) We can (with the appropriate `newtype`) write a `Functor` which maps all the *edge* labels, though.</sub>

Comment: Do you intentionally want the instance to perform DFS?

Comment: @is7s It'd be pretty straightforward to write a `newtype` which utilises some other form of search strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently very few `Foldable` laws, so you can do all sorts of things. In fact, there are several different `Foldable` instances you could write, corresponding to different traversal orders. The `Foldable` laws describe relationships among the different `Foldable` members and, if the type is also a `Functor`, an additional law relating `fold`, `foldMap`, and `fmap`.

Some specifics: There are straightforward "laws" about the relationships between `foldMap`, `foldl`, `foldr`, `sum`, etc., which just say that they should act pretty much like their default implementations except for strictness. For `fold`, this law is `fold = foldMap id`. If the container is also a `Functor`, there's a law specifying that you can go the other way: `foldMap f = fold . fmap f`. Nothing too exciting at all, as I said.

On the other hand, I think trying to combine knot-tying with unique labeling smells a bit funny. I'm not sure what you're up to with that, or whether it really makes sense. The trouble, as I see it, is that although sharing leads to the graph being represented in memory as you want, this sharing is not reflected in the language at all. Within Haskell, a graph with cycles looks exactly like an infinite tree. There is, in fact, very little you can do with a cyclic graph that won't (potentially) turn it into an infinite tree. This is why people bother using things like `Data.Map` to represent graphs in the first place—knot tying doesn't offer a clear view of the graph structure.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the specifics of the two laws you mention? And why do you think knot-tying with unique labelling doesn't make sense?